# What does "-spec" do in Erlang syntax? What is the diffrence if a function is created with or without -spec

Tags: erlang

I am new to erlang programming. I have many doubts. One of them is use of -spec.

What does "-spec" do in Erlang syntax? What is the difference if a function is created with or without -spec

function without -spec

```
add(A, B) ->
    A + B.
```

function with -spec

```
-spec add(Number, Number).
add(A, B) ->
    A + B.
```

I searched on the google but unable to understand the exact use of the -spec. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`spec` adds up information about the code. It indicates the arity of the function and combined with `-type` declarations, are helpful for documentation and bug detection tools.

Tools like Edoc use these type specifications for building documentation.
Tools like Dialyzer use it for static analysis of the code.

So it is not used directly by the running code but many tools use it for better "understanding" the code.

Comment: So there is no harm if I don't use -spec in the erlang module. Thanks for your answer its clear to me now.

Comment: @Shahid, Erlang was invented as a `dynamically typed` language, which means you don't declare the type of a variable, like you do in C/C++.  Some people do not like dynamically typed languages, like C/C++ programmers, so someone tried to make Erlang more like a statically typed language by adding `-spec` and `-type` to the language.   Learning erlang is hard enough without `-spec` and `-type` causing additional confusion.  Forget about them for now, but for a clearer understanding of what they are used for, see http://learnyousomeerlang.com/types-or-lack-thereof

Comment: @7stud, thanks you very much for additional clarification. I too realizing that the learning erlang is very hard in comparison to other languages. But its an  interesting language to learn. Thank you!

Comment: @7stud, I am referring http://learnyousomeerlang.com/ erlang tutorial for my initial learning.  This is very useful and well described erlang tutorial. Thnx!

Comment: @7Stud, I am working on a chat app. I want to fetch a single most recent chat message to show below the chat buddies in recent chat list. I found https://github.com/candy-chat/mod_log_chat_mysql5 but its looking like this is written in an older version of erlang and giving errors when i am compiling it. I just wondering if you have any idea about that. Thanks in advance.